# Git: Best way to handle renaming a lot files

Tags: git, file-rename

I have changed the case of a bunch of filenames in my Git repository.
On my machine, that's not a problem; however, on Linux, it does matter, of course.

How can I assure that the filenames in my repo are the same as on my local file system? In other words, how can I list all files that differ so I can use git mv to change that?

Comment: You could pull the repo. That should up date your files

Answer (score 1):

For me, the best way to handle that was to change the git config to NOT ignore the case.

```
git config --unset-all core.ignorecase && git config --system core.ignorecase false
```

Answer (score 0):

I've handled this sort of problem where you're on a case-insensitive filesystem (like that OS X or Windows uses) and need to test and fix case-sensitive stuff by making a case-sensitive disk image and doing the fixes on that.

1. Make & mount a case-sensitive disk image ([instructions for OS X](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH22247?locale=en_US&viewlocale=en_US)).
2. Clone the repository on the case-sensitive disk image.
3. Test and fix filename casing issues there.
4. Commit & push.

This makes everything much simpler. You can develop and test for a case-sensitive filesystem on a case-sensitive filesystem. `git mv` for recasing filenames will just work and you can do a build and run the tests to ensure everything works.

Keep the case-sensitive disk image around for later use to work on similar problems.